# Angular Schematics: How to reach filesToCreate record set coming from previous operation in a chain?

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I've made a chained schematics and in the first part I generate a module using:

`externalSchematic('@schematics/angular', 'module', moduleOptions)`.

In the second part/element of the chain I call a schematic I've written and I want to edit one of the files added during above module creation. However `tree.visit()` iterates on whole project tree, which is highly unnecessary.

When I log tree/host I see it has a private `_record` and in term that one has a `_filesToCreate` set containing only files created in previous step.

Is there a helper function or property/method of `tree` I'm missing that helps?

**Update**

Adding `tree.getDir(path)` before calling `.visit()`, `path` being specific folder of added files, makes things faster of course.

I just want to know if there is a way to read in my second step of chain, get list of files created/modified in the previous step, since they are kept in host object, I just can't find a way to read that set/list.

Answer (score 0):

When I check [the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/angular_devkit/schematics) I see they are protected members and there seems no public getters or methods exists to expose them for the time being.

‍♀️